# ¿Cómo puedo scrapear desde un csv que contiene múltiples URLs en una columna con simple HTML dom?

Tags: php, csv, simple-html-dom

Ya tengo mi código trabajando para extraer toda la información que necesito de una URL, pero quiero "automatizar" el proceso.

Este es el código con el que extraigo todo lo que necesito de UNA URL con simple HTML dom:

```
    <?php 

    require 'libs/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    $html->load_file('http://url1.com/producto1.html');


    $names = $html->find('h1');
    $manufacturers = $html->find('h2');

       echo $manufacturer->innertext;
       echo '<br>';


       echo $name->innertext;
       echo '<br>';

 ?>
```

Este sería el aspecto del archivo CSV, todas las URLS serían diferentes..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También sé cómo analizar varios enlaces al mismo tiempo, pero eso sirve cuando tienes 1-3 enlaces, no más ya que si no es una locura. Ahora necesito analizar casi 30-50 enlaces de cada archivo csv.

Tengo algunos archivos csv con todos los enlaces que necesito para scrapear, ¿cómo puedo extraer con mi script existente desde un archivo csv (o una lista de url o algo así)?

Comment: Muéstranos una ejemplo del csv, porque a priori, SIMPLE DOM no parece la solución más adecuada.

Comment: He vuelto a editar mi pregunta.

Como digo, no se como INTENTARLO, ya que no veo nada sobre esto por ningún sitio.

Lo que necesito es una manera para crear un loop o algo en esa lista de enlaces.

Si no puede ser en un csv, pues de otra manera.

Comment: A ver, pasito a pasito. Ya tenemos el csv. Ahora para intentarlo has de investigar como abrir y leer archivos, hacer un `split` del archivo (ya que parece que solo contiene URL's) por el delimitador que tengas y eso te creará un array de urls .. luego haces un bucle para que por cada una haga lo que muestra tu codigo de arriba ...

Comment: Gracias!

Por fin algo de luz! Voy a probar...

Comment: Si en vez de un pantallazo hubieras compartido el código hubiera sido sublime, no obstante, es un hilo del que tirar.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario @Muriano, he compartido el código ;) .... el Pantallazo es de el archivo csv... Y no sé para que lo necesitas.

Comment: Lo necesito para ayudarte. Y necesito "el código" porque el pantallazo no lo puedo copiar y pegar en mi editor para hacer pruebas, y como entenderás, no lo voy a copiar a mano.

Comment: @Muriano el código lo puedes copiar sin problemas... 

Para el pantallazo del csv... Si lo que necesitas es las lineas, es un simple copy/paste de la misma url -> http://url1.com/producto1.html

Comment: ¿Por que cargar una librería entera para leer un CSV?, http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php luego con un bucle aplica la "función" de extraer... el como hacerlo para grandes cantidades de URL dependerá de como y quien va a ejecutar esa tarea... yo por ejemplo cuando es algo privado, simplemente seteo el tiempo de ejecución a 0 y listo...

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu csv tenga esta forma:

```
url1.com/producto1.html
url1.com/producto1.html 
url1.com/producto1.html 
url1.com/producto1.html 
url1.com/producto1.html 
url1.com/producto1.html 
url1.com/producto1.html 
url1.com/producto1.html 
url1.com/producto1.html
```

Entonces, podrías:

```
<?php

    require 'libs/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php';



    function scrapUrl($url) 
    {

        $html = new simple_html_dom();

        $html->load_file($url);


        $names = $html->find('h1');
        $manufacturers = $html->find('h2');

        echo $manufacturer->innertext;
        echo '<br>';


       echo $name->innertext;
       echo '<br>';

    }

    $rutaCSV = 'urls.csv'; // Poner aquí la ruta correcta.

    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($rutaCSV));

    print_r($csv); // Verás que es un array donde cada elemento es array con una de las url.

    foreach ($csv as $linea) {

        $url = $linea[0];
        scrapUrl($url);

    }
```

Este código es fácilemente optimizable, sirve únicamente a efectos de indicar cómo deberías tratar el fichero `csv`

Comment: Wow! Gracias @Muriano .. 

Me salta este error -> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object para $name y $manufacturer 

Y no estoy muy seguro de si está cojiendo la url 1 de mi csv para scrapear.

Gracias!!!

Comment: Tendrás que hacer las comprobaciones oportunas, por ejemplo, haz un ´echo $url;´ dentro de `scrapUrl` para comprobar que la url es correcta. O comprobar que existen realmente elementos `h1` y `h2` en el código fuente obtenido.